# How to import a component as prop from another component?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

It is possible to import a component as prop from another component?

For example:

Q-Dialog

```
 <template>
  <q-dialog>       
    <q-layout>
        <q-page-container>
        
          <myCustomComponent />

      </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
  </q-dialog>
</template>

<script>    
//Edited:This works, but I want to register dynamically from props
//import myCustomComponent from "components/MyCustomComponent.vue";

import myCustomComponent from this.myComponent;
    
export default {  
  props: ["myComponent"],
  components: { myCustomComponent }
}
```

Another component:

```
this.$q.dialog({
    component: CustomComponent, //dialog
    myComponent: 'components/MyCustomComponent.vue'
})
```

**Edited**, for better clarify what I am trying to achieve in this case:

My dialog is an *abstract* component in which an unlimited number of different myCustomComponent can be rendered.

To achieve this, I need that the registration of each component (import) is **not** done in the q-dialog.

A solution to consider is to register each component in the file from which the q-dialog is loaded for rendering (different from the q-dialog, in my case the *another component* file) and then pass that path from the imported file to the q-dialog, possibly as props.

Is this possible?

**Edited with solution:**

*Parent* component

```
<script>    
 import registeredComponent from "components/MyCustomComponent.vue";

 export default {
    data() {
      return {        
          myComponent: registeredComponent
      }
    }
        
  methods: {
      btnClickShowDialog(){
          this.$q.dialog({
              component: dialogComponent,
              //pass registered component as prop to dialog
              myCustomComponent: this.myComponent 
          })
      }   
  }
</script>
```

Q-dialog

```
<template>
  <q-dialog>       
    <q-layout>
        <q-page-container>
        
          <component :is="myCustomComponent" />

      </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
  </q-dialog>
</template>

<script>        
    export default {  
      props: ["myCustomComponent"]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pass a component as props and use it in a child Component in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992579/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-component-as-props-and-use-it-in-a-child-component-in-v)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59923758/is-there-any-way-to-load-or-render-components-into-qdialog/59925682#59925682

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my question to better clarify what I am trying to achieve in this case.

Comment: I think Sumurais link is on the right track. With [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) you could load your component in the DOM like `<component :is="myCustomComponent">`

Comment: I've tried this in several ways, but it seems that I necessarily have to register the component (import the component to render as myCustomComponent) in the q-dialog, which I want to avoid for the q-dialog to remain as abstract as possible

Comment: In other words, the q-dialog code would always be the same. when I render the q-dialog from another file with this$q.dialog I would pass all the relevant data and also the registered / imported component, to the q-dialog, possibly as a props

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your q-dialog component you can use the `component` tag to dynamically render a passed in component prop. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-3l9fu3?file=Parent.js).

```html
// q-dialog html
<component :is="myComponent" />
```

In your parent component you'll want to import the desired component, assign it to a data property and pass it in

```js
// parent component js
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent.vue'

data () {
    return {
        passedInComponent: SomeComponent
    }

}
```

```html
// parent component html
<q-dialog :my-component="passedInComponent" />
```

Comment: Thanks LLai. It seems to me that your solution works great for this case. Despite several attempts, I couldn't find a solution based on rendering the q-dialog with this.$q.dialog ({}) from a parent method and passing the q-dialog child component as a prop. A possible solution would be to register the component globally, but I don't want to follow that solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my question with a solution that works for my case. Thanks for the sugestions that helped a lot.

Comment: @josei im glad i could help!